# Verilog Adding value in an always block. SIMPLE

Tags: fpga, verilog

```
module prizes(TESTSSD);
output reg [6:0]TESTSSD;
reg [1:0]equals; 

always @(*) begin
    equals = equals + 1;
    case (equals)
        0: TESTSSD = 7'b0000001;
        1: TESTSSD = 7'b1001111;
        2: TESTSSD = 7'b0010010;
        3: TESTSSD = 7'b0000110;
        4: TESTSSD = 7'b1001100;
        default:TESTSSD = 7'b0000000;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

When I run the code above, I get a messed up looking 2 on the seven segment display; it is missing the middle part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever `equals` changes, you change `equals`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, equals is only 2 bits. How do you ever it expect to have the value 4?

Comment: Right now I am just testing and trying to isolate the issue. Looking at the code I expect to see a one on the seven segment display, but I see a messed up two instead.  If I delete the "equals = equals + 1" I expect to see a zero, and this DOES happen. I also don't expect to see the value 4, it was just there when I was trying to isolate the issue

Comment: When it change to 1, why don't you expect it to trigger the block again and change to 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
always @(*) begin
```

This means whenever any variable that appears on a right-hand side in the block changes, run the block.

```
    equals = equals + 1;
```

This changes the variable `equals`.

So whenever `equals` changes, you increment `equals`. Which means `equals` changes, which means you increment it again, and so on.

So basically, `equals` just keeps incrementing as fast as the hardware can make it happen.

If you output this to a 7-segment display, you will just see the superposition of '0', '1', '2', and '3', flashing as quickly as the hardware can go. This will be much faster than your eye can follow. I don't know what it happens to look like, but if you say it looks like a '2', I believe you.

The usual way to do what you seem to want is to make `equals` increment only when something special happens, like the edge of a slow-ish clock (like maybe 5 Hz at most for the display to be meaningful to the human eye); or only when some special event happens that you're trying to count.

**Edit**

I should also add that, because of race conditions, if you implement this design in real hardware, it's likely that the output doesn't actually transition through all the states 0, 1, 2, 3, as expected, or that it doesn't do it in the order you expect.

For example if you're in the 2'b01 state, you expect to transition to 2'b10. But the signal to change bit 0 might propagate through more quickly than the signal to change bit 1, resulting in a glitch to the 2'b00 state. If that glitch lasts long enough, the circuit might go from there to the 2'b01 state again instead of to 2'b10. But that's just an example. What really happens depends on the transistor-level and wire-geometry level details of how the circuit is built.